# object order with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I would like to sort this object by the PERIOD attribute.

as there are objects and arrays together I'm getting confused, anyone have any ideas?

**My code**

```js
const obj = 
{
  "1": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "Period": 2000,
        "name": "AP 1"
      }
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "Period": 1991,
        "name": "AP 2"
      }
    }
  ],
  "2": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "Period": 1991,
        "name": "AP 3"
      }
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "Period": 2000,
        "name": "AP 4"
      }
    }
  ]
}

_.orderBy(obj, ['Period'], ['asc']);

console.log(obj)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The return structure must be the same input structure.
You do not need to lose the attribute name only the period

**My Expected Code**

```
{
  "1": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "Period": 1991,
        "name": "AP 2"
      }
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "Period": 2000,
        "name": "AP 1"
      }
    }
  ],
  "2": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "Period": 2000,
        "name": "AP 4"
      }
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "Period": 1991,
        "name": "AP 3"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using the version of lodash : 4.17.4

Comment: its unclear what you want to sort.  Could you be more specific about how you want this sorted? Should the inner arrays be sorted?

Comment: What do you mean by "Sort object"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```js
var obj = 
{
  "1": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "Period": 2000,
        "name": "AP 1"
      }
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "Period": 1991,
        "name": "AP 2"
      }
    }
  ],
  "2": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "Period": 2000,
        "name": "AP 3"
      }
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "Period": 1991,
        "name": "AP 4"
      }
    }
  ]
}
 
obj = _.mapValues(obj, function(inner){
   return _.orderBy(inner, ['attributes.Period'], ['dsc']);
});

console.log(obj)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: but the internal objects did not order the smallest period to the largest

Comment: @Max Ferreria they do now!